# TextView to String

Tags: java, android, string, textview

I'm trying to convert TextView into a string and I'm not sure if I'm going about it the right way, below is the code I thought would work but I keep getting errors.

```
TextView test1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result1);
String testA = test1.getText().toString();
```

Is this the correct method to do this or is there another way? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This code is fine, what are the errors?

Comment: It's the right way. What errors?

Comment: Code is correct. Please paste the error from LogCat.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding...I have now realised that this had nothing to do with the error i was getting and I hope ye will be able to help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct. Beware that it will only work once `onCreate` has been called and your `contentView` has been set.